# Ask for prompt() input again if it's empty?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that ask user to input a filename through prompt when page loads.

I want to check if the input is empty and then ask for it again until user inputs something.

Here's my function but its not asking for input again when it's empty.

```
<script>
function fn() {
    var docname="";
     docname = prompt("Please enter the file name:");

}
fn();
while(docname==""){
   fn();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to access a variable which is out of scope.

Comment: Learn how to use your browser's developer tools. You should get a Reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just do it this way

```
function fn() {
    var docname="";
    while(docname==""){
        docname = prompt("Please enter the file name:");
    }   

    return docname;

}


docname = fn();
```